# Wordpress multisite not work wp-admin

Tags: multisite

i have this a multisite, and after that change with redirects, i am lost the wp-admin, i am back configs but the config htaccess if lost. 
i insert domain.site/wp-admin and go to domain.site.
I have this :

Htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and in wp-config

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

define('MULTISITE', true);

define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);

$base = '/';

define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.chromosome.site');

define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');

define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

When did you first install Multisite? The `.htaccess` you're using appears to be from WordPress 3.4 and older. If you started with 3.5 or newer, here's the one you should be using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

See [the Codex `.htaccess` reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) for more.

Comment: Thanks for help, sorry for time of return. I Solved!